# UML Diagrams Extend and Include

Tags: uml, use-case-diagram

I am currently participating in an IT training. Currently we are doing UML Diagrams, our tutor drew a diagram where "extend" and "include" are pointed outside of the system, towards the actors? I think this is wrong. Can someone enlighten me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is nonsense. Extend/Include are for use case connections where the first is about optionality and the second about unconditional inclusion. However, you should not use both unless you know what you are doing since one tends to fall into functional decomposition which is not what UC is all about (namely added value for actors).

Recommended read: Bittner/Spence about UC.